# Errror with method postFlush in Hibernate Interceptors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor

I want to log in my database the operations executed over a table (inserts, updates and deletes). I've been reading about Interceptors, so I implemented my own.

For example, when an Insertion is performed I do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    if (entity instanceof Person) {
        System.out.println("Se ha insertado una persona");
        operation = "Insert";
        date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Finally in the postFlush I do this:

```
// called after committed into database
public void postFlush() {
    System.out.println("postFlush");
    Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    ses.getTransaction().begin();
    Registry reg = new Registry(operation, date);
    ses.save(reg);
    ses.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

In Registry is where I store the information about the operations executed on the table I'm checking.

I had a lot of problems while calling the interceptor on the class with the methods to save, update and delete. After hours reading on the Internet and here (I love this site jeje) I was able to call the interceptor this way:

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(new MyInterceptor).openSession();
```

I run my simple web app to save the name and the country of a person. I was able to store the person's information, but my Registry table was empty. I debugged my code and the method postFlush was never been called. Any ideas? I have followed various tutorials and some recommendations, but nothing seems to work.

The last thing I tried was in a very "dirty" way. I changed my code from this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addPerson(Person p) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(new MyInterceptor).openSession();
    session.save(p);
    logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
}
```

to this (horrendous) way:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addPerson(Person p) {
    MyInterceptor m = new MyInterceptor();
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(m).openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(p);
    tx.commit();
    session.flush();
    m.postFlush();
    logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
}
```

And it worked! I was able to store information of persons and also in Registry, but this isn't the right way eh?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I audit this way, but dates are ugly..

persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="siapen.jpa.interceptor.MeuInterceptador" />
```

java code

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils;
import org.hibernate.CallbackException;
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

import siapen.model.BaseEntity;

public class MeuInterceptador extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7853236444153436270L;

    private String strSQL = "";
    String acao;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    BaseEntity entity;
    String s = "";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // 1
    public boolean onSave(Object obj, Serializable id, Object[] valores, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
            throws CallbackException {
        if (obj instanceof BaseEntity) {
            entity = (BaseEntity) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
                if (valores[i] != null && !valores[i].equals("")) {
                    s += propertyNames[i] + ":" + valores[i];
                    if (i != valores.length - 1) {
                        s += "___";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // 1
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object obj, Serializable id, Object[] valoresAtuais, Object[] valoresAnteriores,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        if (obj instanceof BaseEntity) {
            entity = (BaseEntity) obj;

            for (int i = 0; i < valoresAtuais.length; i++) {

                if (!ObjectUtils.equals(valoresAtuais[i], valoresAnteriores[i])) {
                    if (!s.equals("")) {
                        s += "___";
                    }
                    s += propertyNames[i] + "-Anterior:" + valoresAnteriores[i] + ">>>Novo:" + valoresAtuais[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // 1
    public void onDelete(Object obj, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        if (obj instanceof BaseEntity) {
            entity = (BaseEntity) obj;
        }
    }

    // CHAMADO ANTES DO COMMIT
    // 2
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void preFlush(Iterator iterator) {
    }

    // 3
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        acao = "";
        if (sql.startsWith("/* update")) {
            acao = "update";
        } else if (sql.startsWith("/* insert")) {
            acao = "insert";
        } else if (sql.startsWith("/* delete")) {
            acao = "delete";
        }
        if (acao != null) {
            strSQL = sql;
        }
        return sql;
    }

    // CHAMADO APÓS O COMMIT
    // 4
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        if (acao != null) {
            try {
                if (acao.equals("insert")) {
                    AuditLogUtil audi = new AuditLogUtil();
                    audi.LogIt("Salvo", entity, s);
                }
                if (acao.equals("update")) {
                    AuditLogUtil audi = new AuditLogUtil();
                    audi.LogIt("Atualizado", entity, s);
                }
                if (acao.equals("delete")) {
                    AuditLogUtil audi = new AuditLogUtil();
                    audi.LogIt("Deletado", entity, "");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                strSQL = "";
                s = "";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @erickdeoliveiraleal , I tried your solution and it worked fine until the postFlush method. I changed the code in order to save the operation executed and the date, not the entity.You have `audi.LogIt("Atualizado", entity, s)` and I replace it with `reg = new Registry(operation, date);`

Despite that minor change, still the method postFlush is never executed while running my application.

Comment: Here works perfectly, try to debug this codes and modify it. You can for example use the query instead of comparing fields.

Comment: Hi erick, it works!!! I debugued the code and found an error on mi DAO class, now Im able to audit my data. I just don't know why you said dates were ugly, on my database table they look like this "2017-02-07 16:29:39.07". Anyways, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: maybe a problem here, I need to review my code, when a new timeStamp is modified the old is printed like 2015-07-29 00:00:00.0 and the new one like Sun Jan 29 00:00:00 BRST 2017